# record roadmap/path of visitor on each visit using javascript

Tags: javascript, path, mapping, browser-history

I am developing a web application which requires user path mapping to be stored, i planned doing this with javascript since it will be easy to code. I tried many times and failed. what i want to achieve was like this:

1. check whether a user is visiting the site for the first time, if yes then record all his activities/path, for ex: the main domain is test.com.
   so he might have travelled like this: test.com->test.com/services->test.com/products.
2. Second visit, similarly check condition and start recording his path. for ex: test.com->test.com->contact->test.com/service/2/something...

so this is the basic idea, as we can see we are recording the clicks of a user much like breadcrumbs/trails....

how can this be achieved.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use LocalStorage in HTML5 there store coordinates.

Comment: how can it be done, can you illustrate it with some kind of example. I am familiar with LocalStorage but not sure if i can apply the logic....